# Yumdownloader fails to download postgres dependency

Tags: postgresql, yum, rpm, repository

I am using this command:

```
 sudo yumdownloader --destdir=/opt/test --resolve https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm
```

I get this output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.icm.edu.pl
 * epel: ftp.icm.edu.pl
 * extras: ftp.agh.edu.pl
 * updates: ftp.icm.edu.pl
No Match for argument https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm
Nothing to download
```

I know that link is valid.
I tried changing the name to:

```
pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm    
pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch
```

But it did not help me.
I want to download this package with all it's depedencies.

Probably better to use:

```
# yumdownloader NAME --resolve --installroot=/path/to/installroot --releasever=/
```

Comment: The file you try to download is only repo record and have no dependencies. You can download also with command: `yum install --downloadonly https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm`

Comment: I want to download all depedencies for offline usage. If i use your command and user will have some depedencies this command will not download them.

Comment: Neither your command will. The package you point is repo file, it is not the dabatase

Comment: Ok - so it's my bad, but if i made a correct package name then with command:
`yumdownloader NAME --resolve --installroot=/path/to/installroot --releasever=/`
it will download all depedencies